# WP8.1 SaveRingtoneTask InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, windows, exception, windows-phone-8

I am trying to programmatically set the ringtone of my phone.
Through some search I found this code

```
    private void RingToneSave()
        {
            SaveRingtoneTask ringtoneTask = new SaveRingtoneTask();
            ringtoneTask.Completed += saveRingtoneChooser_Completed;
            ringtoneTask.Source = new Uri(@"C:\Data\Programs\{9519D660-4D38-497F-9584-6497FF78C693}\Install\Craig David.wma");
            ringtoneTask.DisplayName = "Ringtone";
            ringtoneTask.Show();
        }
```

However `ringtoneTask.Show();` throws `System.InvalidOperationException`
Here is the full detailed exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Path must point to a file in your Isolated Storage or Application Data directory.
```

However the path points to a file in my Isolated Storage since I have previously downloaded and saved the file into my isolated storage.
I have also use IsoStorySpy (a tool to check isolated storage of the phone) to make sure that the file is in the Isolated Storage.

Am I understanding wrong the exception? Is there another way to set the ringtone of my phone without using `SaveRingtoneTask`?

**Update**

```
    private void RingToneSave(Uri sURI)
        {
            SaveRingtoneTask ringtoneTask = new SaveRingtoneTask();
            ringtoneTask.Completed += saveRingtoneChooser_Completed;
            ringtoneTask.Source = sURI;
            ringtoneTask.DisplayName = "Ringtone";
            ringtoneTask.Show();
        }

    public async Task<Problem> DownloadFileFromWeb(Uri uriToDownload, string fileName, CancellationToken cToken)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Stream mystr = await DownloadFile(uriToDownload))
                using (IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (ISF.FileExists(fileName))
                    {
                        ISF.DeleteFile(fileName);
                    }
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream file = ISF.CreateFile(fileName))
                    {
                        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;
                        byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

                        int bytesread = 0;

                        while ((bytesread = await mystr.ReadAsync(buf, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
                        {
                            double percentage = ((double)file.Length / (double)mystr.Length) * (double)100;
                            textBlock.Text = Math.Round(percentage).ToString() + "%";
                            cToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                            file.Write(buf, 0, bytesread);
                        }
                        sRingTonePath = file.Name;
                    }

                }
                RingToneSave(new Uri(sRingTonePath));
                return Problem.Ok;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                if (exc is OperationCanceledException)
                    return Problem.Cancelled;
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
                    return Problem.Other;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you're using is invalid, what you should do is download the music file you want in your isolated storage and then point the path as a source.

And no there isn't another way to set the ringtone.

If you just need a way to download ringtones use this [app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/audiko/9nblggh085v1)

```
Stream st = await new WebClient().OpenReadTaskAsync(Link);

 using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream file = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isf))
                {
                    using (var fs = new StreamWriter(file))
                    {
                        byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[st.Length];
                        st.Read(bytesInStream, 0, (int)bytesInStream.Length);
                        file.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
                        file.Flush();
                    }
                }
            }
        }


SaveRingtoneTask task = new SaveRingtoneTask();
task.Source = new Uri(string.Format("isostore:/{0}"selected.FileName),UriKind.Absolute);                    
task.Completed += task_Completed;
task.Show();
```

be sure to change the FileName

Comment: I tried something like this sRingTonePath = Path.GetFullPath(ISF.GetFileNames()[0]); and then used sRingTonePath as source but still same problem.

Comment: I have done this before, I needed it in order to create the app mentioned, the step I followed were

1) Use HttpClient to download the file into a Stream object
2) Create a new file in Isolated Storage (Local Storage) and save the stream in it
3) Start a new RingToneTask and set the Source property to the file created before. Done!

Comment: I am doing the same thing. I updated the question. Is this what you mean?